error while try initialize terraform aws file in vscode

ghassan@Ghassan:~/workspace/terraform$ terraform init

Initializing the backend...

Initializing provider plugins...
- Finding hashicorp/aws versions matching "5.46.0"...
╷
│ Error: Invalid provider registry host
│ 
│ The host "registry.terraform.io" given in provider source address "registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/aws" does not offer a Terraform provider registry.

I try to browse "releases.hashicorp.com" error : HashiCorp , This content is not currently available in your region.

As per Terraform Cloud Content Not Available in Region:

Due to U.S. Government regulation, HashiCorp is required to restrict access to certain assets and engagement in commerce from certain regions and countries.

Trade control documentation can be found at HashiCorp Trade Controls

Honestly, I am trying to learn terraform language. Is there any suggestion to  avoid this matter?
